# How to configure different filter and jersey servlet for 2 url patterns in web.xml?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web.xml, jersey-2.0

I have created different Filter for request. I have done below configuration for that in web.xml :

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
            <param-value>com.core.api.filter.Filter1</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/v1/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
            <param-value>com.core.api.filter.Filter2</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/v2/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

but at time of server startup i am getting below exception :

```
... 6 more
```

Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com -- service jboss.naming.context.java.com
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:106)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:207)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:235)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:193)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:189)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension$2.stepInto(CDIExtension.java:311)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.diveIntoJNDIContext(CDIExtension.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.lookupJerseyConfigJNDIContext(CDIExtension.java:308)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.getInitializedExtension(CDIExtension.java:231)
    ... 23 more

16:20:25,252 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address:

I tried out to google it but not found much help for same .

Please help me to get out from this this issue.....

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to use two different filters may be you have to use `<filter-mapping>` tag.

From [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html):

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Compression Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>CompressionFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>compressionThreshold</param-name>
        <param-value>10</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Compression Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>CompressionTest</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CompressionTest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>CompressionTest</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CompressionTest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/CompressionTest</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```